# MobaXterm log file

Tags: windows, unix, terminal, cygwin, mobaxterm

For reasons unknown yet, my MobaXterm Local Terminal will not start any more on Windows 7 box. There is not even a single error prompt of why this may be happening. I am still able to ssh into remote hosts. Could someone please suggest how to turn on logging in MobaXterm of all its events etc. so that I can debug this break?

Alternatively any explanation on why only the MobaXterm  Local Terminal may not start in the application would also be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what it the reference to cygwin ?

Comment: CygUtils.plugin is in the same directory as MobaXterm.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround for now is to revert to a previous version of MobaXterm (agree.. not the best solution).
-- Uninstalled MobaXterm 9.1
-- Reinstalled MobaXterm 8.6

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily we need to move to an old revision. I hope we can take any latest stable branches (not installer) portable edition, and use it.

If this works, there was something goofed up in the installer folder.

This portable edition can be continued, for same configuration and other settings, copy and paste the `MobaXterm.ini` file from your old location and check if that restores all your settings or crashes.

If this crash, this is day clear of the reason, else we have the old favourite restored.